# Incorrect syntax highlighting Vim (Actionscript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, vim, syntax-highlighting

The braces shown below after `...ret):String` are incorrectly being highlighted as red

I'm using the following syntax definition file for actionscript:

- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1061

[image]

2 Questions:

1. Does anyone happen to know off-hand what causes this weird matching?
2. Is there anyway of identifying the current syntax matching group under the cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's because the syntax file doesn't support anonymous functions. I guess usually (in many other languages) that's an error? Fix it by removing `syn match   actionScriptInParen     contained "[{}]"` from actionscript.vim.
2. I don't know.